# I want to combine two different size pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Based on the data below I would need to achieve the following:

DataFrame1

```
index1 value1
1      one
2      two
3      three
4      four
5      five
6      six
7      seven
```

DataFrame2

```
index2 value2
3      just
6      done
```

combine DataFrame1 and DataFrame2 to DataFrame3

```
index value1 value2
1      one    <none>
2      two    <none>
3      three  just
4      four   just
5      five   just
6      six    done
7      seven  done
```

DataFrame3 has the same size of DataFrame1, and the match in value2 when index1>=index2. How can this be done in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming in your data that `index` are actual indexes and not columns named "index". If so, you can solve this quickly with a `join()` and front filling. Otherwise you'd need to use merge, or `set_index()` previously:

Based on your dataset:

```
df_1.join(df_2).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Returns:

```
       value1 value2
index1              
1         one    NaN
2         two    NaN
3       three   just
4        four   just
5        five   just
6         six   done
7       seven   done
```

Full working example with `set_index()`:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'index1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                     'value1':['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']}).set_index('index1')
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'index2':[3,6],
                     'value2':['just','done']}).set_index('index2')
print(df_1.join(df_2).fillna(method='ffill'))
```